DB2 to Postgres Migration: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
I'm trying to rewrite IBM DB2 Queries to PostgreSQL.
According to DB2 UDB TO POSTGRESQL CONVERSION GUIDE the DB2 function CURRENT_TIMESTAMP can be migrated to the Postgres function CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. I don't think it's that simple.
According to this question and the documentation

PostgreSQL provides a number of functions that return values related to the current date and time. These SQL-standard functions all return values based on the start time of the current transaction

In other words, if there are multiple insert or update statements in a transaction that set the value of an attribute to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, this timestamp will be the exact same for all rows. This behavior is different from DB2: DB2 uses the actual timestamp in each statement.
So I came across the Postgres functions clock_timestamp() and statement_timestamp().
I think the function statement_timestamp() is the right function to replace CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DB2. However, I can not find any documentation that would confirm my assumption. I want to be sure that there are no side-effects when replacing all CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with statement_timestamp() - can someone confirm this?

From the manual:

PostgreSQL also provides functions that return the start time of the
current statement, as well as the actual current time at the instant
the function is called.

And a test in SQL:
BEGIN;
    SELECT clock_timestamp();
    SELECT pg_sleep(1);
    SELECT clock_timestamp();
COMMIT;


CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DB2 within a single SQL statement: "all values are based on a single clock reading", see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=registers-current-timestamp In postgres, clock_timestamp() changes during statement execution. But I would like to understand or have confirmed that using statement_timestamp() has no side-effects when replacing all CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DB2.
